# BER vs SNR measurement in a Digital communication system

Tags: communication, digital-communications, telecommunications

To analyse the performance of any communication system, BER vs SNR graphs are used.

For a digital system like this one (Assume there is only one signal, so mux & demux are not required)

[image]

SNR is measured before demodulating and BER is measured for the digital sequence after Source decoder.

Is this the right way of plotting BER vs SNR graphs?

Comment: A BER could be defined for any point after the demodulator, depending on whether it's being used to qualify the overall system or help improve the demodulator or FEC algorithms. FER is also a measure that tends to be more relevant for some systems. The tendency today is to consider the physical layer along with the lower level protocols, so what you're doing isn't neecssarily right for 'any' comms system. However, SNR is in the right place, degrade it with AWGN or other insults added in the channel, just make sure the place for BER/FER is relevant to the particular system under study.

Answer (score 1):

In general, what you have shown and said is correct. For a fixed transmission rate \$R\$, a BER vs SNR curve will show you how well the receiver works with changing SNR levels and is arguably one of the best ways too assess overall receiver performance. The SNR value where the BER is \$10^{-9}\$ is usually noted and specified in the transceiver's datasheet as the transceiver receive sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Your presumption of SNR being measured before demodulation is flawed. SNR is measured after demodulation. S in SNR indicates the signal ie individual bit power. Before demodulation CNR is measured which is Carrier to Noise Ratio.
Now since BER and SNR are measured after demodulation, their comparison is justified.
SNR essentially denotes the amount of degradation in your signal(bits) per unit noise while CNR denotes the amount of carrier degradation due to noise. CNR and SNR do not essentially have a linear relation because of the noise added by the demodulator and the performance of your FEC.

Answer (score 0):

All the BER testers I have made did not require encryption or checksum, but rather just raw packet data compared with the Tx binary data XOR’d to count both packet error rate and bit position  of the error. Also cumulative BER counts per bits vs SNR are plotted on log-log XY graph.

. I then used different data patterns of  worse case, best case and random data to determine the difference in threshold for  some ratio like 1e-12 to 1e-6.

Both the knee of the curve at some dB SNR and slope  in dB/decade of BER are strong indicators of comparison to ideal for opportunities for improvement. Obviously error correction and its overhead and burst correction capability extend the knee and may affect the slope for soft correctable and uncorrectable errors by a known amount depending on the types of noise.